# simple ways to create RESTful Web Service (java/python/?) in OSX to test ios app with swift

Tags: ios, swift, web-services, restful-url

I am new on this gurus, as titled, please advise, which solution out there is more popular and/or adopt by the marketplace better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would write a small application in Node.js. It's super lightweight and handles JSON natively which has been the norm. Pretty well suited for RESTful development.

There's a library that makes RESTful development a breeze called [node-restify](http://mcavage.me/node-restify/). Their documentation is straight forward and will walk you through writing the most basic web service in a few lines of code.

If you've never used Node.js before it's easy to try out. Comes with an installer for OS X, https://nodejs.org/.